# py2neo | TypeError: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I have seen a reference **http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/07/23/neo4j-loading-json-documents-with-cypher/**
to Load JSON data with cypher to convert into graph-database structure. But I'm getting

**TypeError: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'**

My code snippet is -

```
graph = Graph()

with open('test.json') as data_file:
    json = json.load(data_file)

query = """
RETURN {json}
"""

# Send Cypher query.
print graph.cypher.execute(query, json = json)
```

Comment: What version of py2neo are you using? Your code snippet runs fine on py2neo 2.0.8.

Comment: Thanks, I was using 2.0.0. Its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Very bad idea to call your variable json.
Start by trying to call it some other name ...